# How to align center text with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag which contains text, and I want to align the contents of this div vertically center.

Here is my div style:

```
 div {
     height: 200px;
     line-height: 200px;
     text-align: center;
     border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
   }
   span {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     line-height: normal;
   }
```

Here is my html

```
 <div>
   <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Haec et tu ita posuisti, et verba vestra sunt. Non enim iam stirpis bonum quaeret, sed animalis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Haec et tu ita posuisti, et verba vestra sunt. Non enim iam stirpis bonum quaeret, sed animalis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Haec et tu ita posuisti, et verba vestra sunt. Non enim iam stirpis bonum quaeret, sed animalis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Haec et tu ita posuisti, et verba vestra sunt. Non enim iam stirpis bonum quaeret, sed animalis.</span>
 </div>
```

I wanna text like in image below:-

i.stack.imgur.com/a5wQe.png

Comment: @ImranAli are you sure users with `1` rep can post images?

Answer (score -1):

> Giving `display:table` to `div` and `display:table-cell` to `span`
>   will do the trick .

```css
div {
     

     text-align: center;
     border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
     display:table;
     height:300px;
   }
   span {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
   
   }
```

```html
<div>
   <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Haec et tu ita posuisti, et verba vestra sunt. Non enim iam stirpis bonum quaeret, sed animalis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Haec et tu ita posuisti, et verba vestra sunt. Non enim iam stirpis bonum quaeret, sed animalis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Haec et tu ita posuisti, et verba vestra sunt. Non enim iam stirpis bonum quaeret, sed animalis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Haec et tu ita posuisti, et verba vestra sunt. Non enim iam stirpis bonum quaeret, sed animalis.</span>
 </div>
```